# Why won't pip install the version I am specifying in requirements.txt?

Tags: docker, pip

I have a requirements.txt file:

```
confluent-kafka==1.9.2
google-cloud-bigquery==3.4.0
protobuf==3.20.3
setuptools
```

And a Dockerfile:

```
ARG TAG=latest
FROM gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/python39-template-launcher-base:${TAG}

ARG WORKDIR=/opt/dataflow
RUN mkdir -p ${WORKDIR}
WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}

ARG TEMPLATE_NAME=dataflow_flex_test
COPY . ${WORKDIR}

ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE=${WORKDIR}/${TEMPLATE_NAME}/main.py
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_SETUP_FILE=${WORKDIR}/setup.py

RUN apt-get update \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip \
    && pip install 'apache-beam[gcp]==2.40.0' \
    && pip install --force-reinstall -r ${WORKDIR}/requirements.txt \
    && pip freeze

RUN python setup.py install
ENV PIP_NO_DEPS=True
```

When I build the image however and run pip freeze it shows

```
protobuf==4.21.8
```

How can I get pip to install the version of protobuf I have specified in my requirement.txt? Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

here is the setup.py file referenced at the end of the Dockerfile:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='dataflow-flex-test',
    version='0.1.0',
    install_requires=[],
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    description='dataflow flex test',
    author='XX'
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it might be a dependency for another package you are trying to install. try to add --no-deps flag, and then pip will only install the packages specified in requirements.txt without considering their dependencies.

pip install --force-reinstall -r ${WORKDIR}/requirements.txt --no-deps